# Jquery ul li item placement after removed

Tags: jquery, user-interface, indexing, scrollto, listitem

I am currently working on a piece of UI code that when a photo is uploaded, it uploads dynamically using a template. With that an image is re-sized in a small square `li` element. The purpose for that is the more people upload photos, the top `li` act as a management panel to scroll to the image they want to edit or delete.

I have everything working except for the issue when removing the image from the `li`. I use the dynamically created `li` index to match the top `li` index in order to scroll to the correct image. When I delete the image it deletes JUST that index position. Ideally I would like the image to move over the index and remain sorted.

-Html
(supposed to look like this)

```
<ul class="mainul">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
</ul>
```

-If Upload it will look like this

```
<ul class="mainul">
<li><img blah blah blah></li> "index 0"
<li><img blah blah blah></li>  "index 1"
<li><img blah blah blah></li>  "index 2"
<li><img blah blah blah></li>  "index 3"
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
</ul>
```

-Template attaching to main UL

```
<script type="text/html" id="test1">
    {{#upload}}<li><img src="{{ fpath }}" alt="" height="38" width="38"/></li>{{/upload}}
        </script>
```

** The problem is if I try to delete an image at let's say index 2, I would like all images from 2 on to collapse to the index that has just been removed.

-Code I toyed with so far

```
$.fn.exchangePositionWith = function (selector) {
               var other = $(selector);
                this.after(other.clone());
                other.after(this).remove();
          };




 $("#output2").on("click", ".deletimg", function () {
                var value = $(this).attr("data-id");
                var Id = 0;
                var Id = $(this).closest("li").index();
                $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id) + ')').find('img').remove();
                $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id) + ')').text(Id);
                $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id) + ')').exchangePositionWith('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id - 1) + ')');
                // $("#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id) + ')')".exchangePositionWith("#thumb-top li:eq(i)");
                // $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (Id) + ')').find('img').text(Id);

                alert(Id);
            });
```

---

```
 var srcid = $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').find('img').attr('src');
                var srcid2 = $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').next().find('img').attr('src');
                var srcposition = $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').next().index()
                var srcposition2 = $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').nextAll().index()
                if (typeof srcid2 === 'undefined') {
                    $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').find('img').remove();
                    $('#thumb-top').appendTo(srcposition2);
                };
                $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (srcposition) + ')').find('img').remove();
                $('#thumb-top li:eq(' + (dataid) + ')').find('img').attr('src', srcid2);
```

-Farthest I got was to remove and replace images that were right by each other in terms of indexes.

Comment: *"I would like the image to move over the index and remain sorted."* Not at all clear what this means. Can you show the deletion code you have now, and an example of the `LIs` you'd like to see before and after deletion?

Comment: Sorry man, first time posting. A little unclear of how to explain the situation my self lol, but I gave it a shot hope I didn't confuse you. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I needed was two arrays and two for loops. One array for getting all the `LI` siblings. So my for loop iterated over a constant amount of `LI` elements using jquery to find img. I would come up with results in the first couple of `LI` elements for example index 1,2,3 and four in my array will contain a path to an image. If I delete an image from an LI, I use the second for loop to splice the the first array to remove the "undefined" values. This will always give me results where if I delete an image path in the middle of an `LI`, that will get removed and re appended to the the main `UL` by filtering it through the Arrays.